# $T_1, ... , T_n$ time of life of instruments with geometric distribution of parameter p independent

Tags: probability

$T_1, ... , T_n$ time of life of instruments with geometric distribution of parameter p independents. 
I define S as the first n instants of failure and U as the last n instant of failure. 
I want to find the law of S and the density of U.

This is what I did so far:

To find the law of S I start by calculating: 
$$\mathbb{P}(S = k) = \mathbb{P}(S \geq k) - \mathbb{P}(S \geq k + 1) $$
$$\mathbb{P}(S = k) = \mathbb{P}(S < k+1) - \mathbb{P}(S < k)$$ 
But here I am stuck on what I should do because I still do not know the distribution.

I do the same reasoning with U as follows:
$$ \mathbb{U}(S = k) = \mathbb{U}(U \leq k) - \mathbb{U}(S \leq k + 1) $$
But I still get nowhere.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Following the suggestions I managed to say that:

$$\mathbb{P}(S=k) = [\mathbb{P}(T_1 \geq k)]^n = [1 -\mathbb{P}(T_1 < k)]^n = $$
$$ = [1 - [1-(1-p)^k]^n = [(1-p)^k]^n $$

Now the exercise asks me to identify random variable, saying it is a geometric distribution with parameter $1-(1-p)^n$. However I am struggling to see how this is true.

Moreover, how should I study U? Is it the maximum instead of the minimum? I would love to see a hint of solution using my procedure as well.

Comment: If I understand correct then $S=\min(T_1,\dots,T_n)$ so that $P(S\geq k)=P(T_1\geq k,\dots,T_n\geq k)=P(T_1\geq k)^n$. Does that help?

Comment: Can you follow it up? I am not sure where this is going.

Comment: @qcc101 you have an expression for $P(T_1\geq k)$ because you know $T_1 \sim Geo(p)$ thus substitute it into what drhab found to get an expression for $P(S \geq k)$...

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 From this I found that: $[\mathbb{P}(T_1 \geq k)]^n =  [(1-p)^k]^n$. Is this distribution equivalent to a geometric distribution of parameter       $1-(1-p)^n$? Anyway, I would love to solve this exercise also with my procedure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all defining $S$ as the "first n instants [sic] of failure" makes little sense, as you have only been given $n$ lifetimes, so for there to be $n$ instances of failure would require all $n$ lifetimes to terminate. This confusion is likely why Drhab commented as such, suggesting instead to look at $S=\min\{T_1,\dotsc,T_n\}$ and provided the general formula for all minimums of IIDRVs: $P(S> k)=P(T_1> k)^n$. This is interpreted as the *first instance of failure* out of the $n$ lifetimes, i.e. the minimum lifetime.

Then, with $P(T_1\leq k)=1-(1-p)^k$ (assuming CDF corresponding to when the $T_i$ take values in $\mathbb{N}$), we first have $P(T_1>k)=(1-p)^k=:q^k$ where $q=1-p$ for ease of notation. Then substituting, we have $P(S>k)=(q^k)^n=(q^n)^k$, so that indeed $P(S\leq k)=1-(q^n)^k$ is the CDF of a Geometric RV with new parameter $\tilde{p}=1-q^n=1-(1-p)^n$.

How can we tackle $U$? Well, let's see how that minimum formula was derived in the first place and hope that informs us on a similar manner to derive a formula for the maximum of IIDRVs.

If the minimum of $n$ variables is greater than a number $k$, then all of those variables must be greater than $k$, i.e the following set equalities hold
$$\{\min\{T_1,\dotsc, T_n\} >k\}=\{T_1 >k,\dotsc, T_n>k\}.$$
That's just from the definition of minimum. Thus, taking probabilities and writing $S=\min\{S_1,\dotsc, S_n\}$, we have
$$P(S >k)=P(T_1>k, \dotsc, T_n>k),$$
and finally the IID assumption greatly simplifies the RHS further, to
$$P(S>k)=P(T_1>K)P(T_2>k)\cdot \dotsc \cdot P(T_n >k),$$
first using independence, then using the identical distributions, we finally get
$$P(S>k)=P(T_1>k)^n.$$

Can you now, after seeing this argument for minimum, derive the analogous formula for maximums? Please comment for further clarification.

**EDIT**
If $U=\max\{T_1,\dots, T_n\}$, then we know that $P(U\leq k)=P(T_1 \leq k)^n=(1-q^{k})^n$ by definition of maximum and since the $T_i$ are IID. To find $\mathbb{E}(U)$ we use the [alternative formula for expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value) for discrete non-negative RVs:
$$E(U)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(U\geq k).$$
Since $P(U\geq k)=1-P(U\leq k-1)=1-(1-q^{k-1})^n,$ we must compute the series,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1-(1-q^{k-1})^n.$$
In principle this series can always be computed by using the binomial theorem to expand $(1-q^{k-1})^n$ and then use theory of geometric series to compute the resulting series' in closed form. For $n=2$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(U)=\frac{3-2p}{p(2-p)}\approx 2.667$$
when $p=0.5$, for example.

Comment: Super clear. I managed to solve the one with U as well, finding that $f_U(k) = [1-(1-p)^k]^n - [1-(1-p)^{k-1}]^n$ which is indeed the right solution. Let's say I want to find $\mathbb{E}[U]$ as well. By linearity, I write: $$ \mathbb{E}[U] = \mathbb{E}[U+S] - \mathbb{E}[S] $$ The expected value of S is easy because it is geometrically distributed. How should I find the expected value of the sum of U and S? (Is this a good procedure to simplify the problem?) Edit: with n = 2

Comment: @qcc101 Thanks. I have added an edit demonstrating how to compute $\mathbb{E}(U)$ with the analytic answer for $n=2$, as an example and its numerical value for when $p=0.5$. Your idea would require knowing the PDF or CDF of $U+S$ which is not immediately known. Better to compute the expected value by definition or become familiar with the alternative formula I cite—extremely useful in the case of non-negative RVs and perusing the Wikipedia link, you will notice an analogous version for continuous non-negative RVs, as well. Hope this helps.